# Craco facing @font-face SyntaxError

Tags: css, webpack, font-face, craco

I have an ElectronJS + ReactJS app. The application is set up by following [this guide on MongoDB's](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/node/integrations/electron-cra/) website. Currently I'm using the Chakra UI kit for my front end which then led me to [this documentation](https://chakra-ui.com/community/recipes/using-fonts#option-1-install-with-npm) on how to use fonts with Chakra UI.

However, after downloading the `@fontsource/lato` package using npm, and following the steps in the documentation, when I `import '@fontsource/lato'` into the file, my app will show a blank page and the console throws this error

```
Uncaught C:\Users\user\Documents\Project Intern\project-intern\node_modules\@fontsource\lato\index.css:2
@font-face {
^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at new Script (node:vm:100:7)
    at createScript (node:vm:265:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (node:vm:313:10)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1083:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1130:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1229:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1044:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:885:12)
    at f._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:13330)
    at o._load (node:electron/js2c/renderer_init:2:3109)
```

I think it has something to do with the Webpack configuration as I'm using Craco, but I don't know how to set up the configurations in Craco.

This is my `craco.config.js` file.

```js
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");
module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: {
      target: "electron-renderer",
      externals: [
        nodeExternals({
          allowlist: [/webpack(\/.*)?/, "electron-devtools-installer"],
        }),
      ],
    },
  },
};
```

I appreciate any help given in advance!